# Flutter: ¿Como evitar que mi sesión expire, después de haberme logueado?

Tags: nodejs, flutter, dart, autenticación

Estoy desarrollando mi primera app en flutter, y en un principio tengo el siguiente login, que al ser ejecutado, responde satisfactoriamente: 
[image: Login de la App]

La app se loguea correctamente y debe enviar 2 parametros a la siguiente pantalla:

[image: Codigo del Logueo]

En la siguiente pantalla se debe enviar los datos del cliente hacia el servidor y guardarlos en base de datos: 
[image: Segundo formulario a llenar]

Al querer guardar los datos, se debe hacer un post con la informacion, **EL PROBLEMA ES QUE AL HACER EL POST EL SERVIDOR RESPONDE LO SIGUIENTE:**
[image: Respuesta del POST]

Mi servidor tiene la siguiente funcion, que tiene un candado para verificar que la sesión este activa:
[image: Funcion de seguridad en el backend]

El problema es que al hacer login correctamente la sesion deberia seguir activa, pero por alguna razon al cambiar de pagina esta expira, que solucion podrian darme?

Comment: es un tema de server no de flutter, revisa que tipo de autenticación estás usando, si te responde algún token ,  entonces debes almacenarlo en tu dispositivo para usarlo en las siguientes peticiones

Comment: @diegoveloper lo que me incomoda es que ya he desarrollado aplicaciones antes en Ionic, con el mismo tipo de Login, y siempre han funcionado bien, sin cerrar mi sesion.

Comment: segun lo que veo en el código del server estas usando socket, pero en flutter solo usas una llamada http,  puedes buscar el paquete socketio

Comment: Hey, tenes razon, en Ionic usaba socket, muy acertado tu comentario.